# SQLExceptionjava.sql.SQLException: ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol

Tags: java, oracle

My database upgraded to 19c, after that when i am trying connect DB i am getting below error.
Some one pls help on below issue:
SQLExceptionjava.sql.SQLException: ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol

Comment: what is your version of ojdbc that you use?

Comment: the version of you oracle client is too old, upgrade it or you need to add the following parameters to the database server SQLNET.ora:
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_CLIENT = 8
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER = 8

Comment: Data base upgrade version 19 c (latest) and As per Data Base team, They are not suppose to add SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_CLIENT = 8 SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER = 8.   Could you please suggest any other way to resolve the issue?  Thanks A lot

Comment: Currently i am using classes12.jar to connect, Do you i think i need to upgrade latest jars? (also tried same but not working)

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked when I changed the classpath from classes12.jar to ojdbc6.jar. My code was running on java 1.6.